# Using ggplot in a function

Tags: r, ggplot2, rlang

I am trying to create a function in r using ggplot. This is my code so far:

```
breakchart<-function(df,x,y) {
  ggplot(df,aes( {{x}} ,{{y}}))  + geom_point() +
    ylim(-20,20) + xlim(-20,20) + 
    geom_hline(yintercept = 0) +
    geom_vline(xintercept = 0) + 
    ggtitle(" Break Chart")
```

This has worked. However, I want to add a color aesthetic to my graphing function.
**EXAMPLE: ggplot(df,aes( x , y, color = ??)) + geom_point()**

I am not sure how to do this without causing an error. Does anybody have an idea how to do this?
Thanks

Comment: Does it not work if you just use the same approach as for `x` and `y`? ie, `aes({{ x }}, {{ y }}, color = {{ color }})`? What have you tried, and what error are you seeing?

Comment: Yes, it worked- had to adjust something small in the code when I was defining the function. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The approach you've already taken works for me.

```r
library(ggplot2)

breakchart<-function(df, 
                     x,
                     y, 
                     colour, 
                     ylim = c(-20, 20), 
                     xlim = c(-20, 20),
                     title = "Break chart") {
  ggplot(df,
         aes(x = {{x}},
             y = {{y}},
             colour = {{colour}})
         )  + 
    geom_point() +
    ylim(ylim) + xlim(xlim) + 
    geom_hline(yintercept = 0) +
    geom_vline(xintercept = 0) + 
    ggtitle(title) 
}

breakchart(mtcars, wt, mpg, col = factor(cyl))
#> Warning: Removed 14 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-03-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you, just had to adjust something small in the code while defining the function.

Comment: If this answers your question, please accept the answer (mark it as accepted)